Configure 3proxy to filter domains before going through the proxy
My server is 1.111.111.111 running 3proxy(above is the config of 3proxy)
How to make sure that when the client connects to one of the two ports 10000 and 10001, if the request is ip-api.com, it will go direct (ie use 194.62.167.133 , not through abc:30000 or abc:30001.
I mean when the client request uses a proxy 1.111.111.111:10000 or 10001,the request is to the domain ip-api.com/json, ip-api.com will return ip 1.111.111.111
If the client requests to api.ipify.org/format=json, api.ipify.org will return the ip of socks abc:30000 or abc:30001 depending on port 10000 or 10001 that the client is using.
nserver 8.8.8.8
nserver 8.8.4.4
nscache 65536
timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
log /var/log/3proxy/3proxy.log D
rotate 30
allow *
parent 1000 socks5 abc:30000
socks -p10000
flush
allow *
parent 1000 socks5 abc:30001
socks -p10001
flush
